# error with yum update

Tags: centos, centos7

I'm trying to do yum update on my centos 7 server but i'm getting the following error:

```
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for grub2-tools which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of grub2-tools of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude grub2-tools.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of grub2-tools installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of grub2-tools installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: 1:grub2-tools-2.02-0.64.el7.centos.x86_64 != 1:grub2-tools-2.02-0.44.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, due to abnormal stop of yum update process.

I solve by removing grub2-tools and then re-install it, skipping the multilib check.

Specifically here's what I did:

[CAUTION! Use at your own risk ]

```
yum remove grub2-tools
yum install grub2 --setopt=protected_multilib=false
yum clean all
yum update
```

Answer (score 0):

I manually download a higher version of grub2-tools (the 2.02-0.64) from

```
https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=grub2-tools&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=
```

And then I've manually installed it

```
rpm -ivh grub2-tools-2.02-0.64.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

The process failed by dependencies, as it needed grub2-common at least same version (2.02-0.64), so I manually download also, and manually install bot

```
rpm -ivh grub2-common-2.02-0.64.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh grub2-tools-2.02-0.64.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

So the problem seems resolved.